# Couldnot connect to smtp.gmail.com at port 465

Tags: java, smtp, gmail

I am developing an application in which i have to send mail through java code. I am using smtp.gmail.com as server and port 465(also tried 25 and 567). The same code is running well on my friend's system. But in my system, it is showing exception. Even telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 is not getting connected.help please

Comment: Firewall? Proxy? Which exception?

Comment: Have a look at the stacktrace of the exception it will mention the problem.

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 465... this is exception i am getting... i tried
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 from command prompt ....there also it gives "connection fails" error

Comment: You probably need SSL on ports 465 and 567.

Comment: I did it, and the same code is running well in my friend's system ...what should i do ...

Comment: Port 25 is probably blocked by your ISP, port 465 and 567 probably need SSL. If your code is working on another system, verify your firewall and router config.

Comment: i tried all, but not getting result. I disable firewall and antivirus also

Answer (score 0):

```
final String from = "aijopc@gmail.com";
            final String password = "aijopc@123";
            String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.host", host);
            props.put("mail.user", from);
            props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
            props.put("mail.defaultEncoding", "UTF-8");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
            // props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", host);
```